# Ruby/Watir select a choice from a drop down menu

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

Hello I am relatively new to QA automated web testing and I try to use SO as a last resort.

That being said I am having issues selecting a choice from a drop down menu in our web app.

Here is the following code:

```
<div id="edit-main-user-role-wrapper" class="form-item">
    <select id="edit-main-user-role" class="form-select my-dropdown ahah-processed" name="main[user_role]" style="display: none;"></select>
    <div class="newListSelected" style="position: static;">
        <span class="selectedTxt">

            Student

        </span>
        <ul class="newList" style="top: -136px; height: 136px; left: 0px; display: none;">
            <li>
                <a class="" href="JavaScript:void(0);"></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I inspect the drop down icon with Firefox inspect element it directs me to this line in the code: span class="selectedTxt"

I have tried accessing the list by id, class, xpath, and css all to no avail.

Here are some of my past attempts:

```
@browser.div(:class => 'form-item').select_list(:text => 'Student').fire_event ("on click")

@browser.select_list(:xpath, menu).option(:text, option).click
```

Comment: I have looked at the various other dropdown related questions on SO, but none of those were able to help me address my issue.

Comment: Still working on it, but I've made progress. This will at least "drop" the drop down menu.
@browser.span(:class, "selectedTxt").click

Answer (score 2):

An element with a select tag should only be meaningful if there are elements with option tags nested inside it. Often these pages have a lot of extra javascript in them to give context.

For dropdowns that don't follow the select/option pattern, you want to click on the element that drops down the list, and then click on the element you want that becomes visible as a result.

Answer (score 1):

This is what eventually worked for me:

```
@browser.span(:class, "selectedTxt").click   # to make the list visible
@browser.element(:xpath, "#{xpath}").click   # click on the specified xpath
```

I know this may not be the most elegant answer, but it works!

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you're still looking for answers, but either of these worked for me:

```
  @browser.select_list(:id => "you_leaving_us").option(:text => "Other").select
@browser.select_list(:id => "you_leaving_us").option(:value => "8").select
```

Instead of li's, I had options. Hope it works